# Prevent other sudoers to use apt-get command

Tags: sudo, privileges

How can I prevent other sudoers to run `apt-get install` command? Other commands such as `mount` and others are OK with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't! If you wish to give root access to an user, nothing can stop him from do anything he want with the system. Root privileges means no restrictions. So, better, give to an user only the permissions he needs.